# Different proofs for two squares theorem for primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, math-history

There is a proof of two squares theorem for primes of form $4k+1$ from quadratic forms and there is a proof from Bolyai using Gaussian integers. I am reasonably sure such a nice simple statement has more than two proofs. What are the different proofs for the two squares theorem? Please provide one complete proof per answer.

Comment: Two squares theorem = the theorem on *what natural numbers* can be expressed as the sum of two squares, or you only want what primes are the sum of two squares? Can you give links to the proofs you're referring to?

Comment: "two squares theorem for primes of form 4k+1"

Comment: Chekc here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares#Zagier.27s_.22one-sentence_proof.22

Comment: Unless you further edit this question, it's unclear what you're asking. I am *guessing* that you want an elementary proof that ever prime of the form $4k + 1$ has a representation as a sum of two squares.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're referring to an elementary result which maybe Fermat did actually prove.

If a prime number $p \,\in\, \mathbb{Z}^+ \,$ is the sum of two squares, then either that prime is $2$ or that prime is one more than a multiple of $4$. That is to say, if $p = m^2 + n^2$ has a solution in integers, then $p = 2$ or $p \,\equiv\, 1 \pmod 4 \,$.

This is easy enough to prove with modular arithmetic. If an odd number is the sum of two squares, then one square must be odd and the other even. If $m \equiv 2 \mod 4$, then $m^2 \equiv 0 \mod 4$. And if $m \equiv 3 \mod 4$, then $m^2 \equiv 1 \mod 4$. So $m^2 + n^2 \equiv 3 \mod 4$ is impossible, and therefore a prime of the form $4k + 3$ can't be the sum of two squares.

Comment: both directions are needed. what are the flags supposed to be for?

Comment: Again, you're being unclear. I'm *guessing* that you're referring to the "flag this comment" feature. This is for comments that are "rude or offensive, not constructive, obsolete, too chatty, or other."